# Error - getHostByAddr ENOTFOUND ::ffff:18.234.32.226

Tags: node.js, dns, reverse-dns

When I use this utility with nodejs:  https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_reverse_ip_callback

like so:

```
  const {remoteAddress, remotePort} = req.connection; 

  dns.reverse(remoteAddress, (err, hostnames) => {

    if(err){
      console.error(err.message);
    }

  });
```

I get that error -

> getHostByAddr ENOTFOUND ::ffff:18.234.32.226

what is the ffff stuff at the beginning of the address/ip? I assume I should get rid of that before passing to the dns.reverse lookup call?

Answer (score 0):

`::ffff:18.234.32.226` is an IPv4 address (`18.234.32.226`) mapped as an IPv6 one, which you detect because of the use of `:`.

This is a common case that happens on systems configured to prefer IPv6 over IPv4 (something you can configure in Unix systems with the file `/etc/gai.conf`).

It is explained in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3493 section 3.7:

> The API also provides a different type of compatibility: the ability
> for IPv6 applications to interoperate with IPv4 applications.  This
> feature uses the IPv4-mapped IPv6 address format defined in the IPv6
> addressing architecture specification [2].  This address format
> allows the IPv4 address of an IPv4 node to be represented as an IPv6
> address.  The IPv4 address is encoded into the low-order 32 bits of
> the IPv6 address, and the high-order 96 bits hold the fixed prefix
> 0:0:0:0:0:FFFF.  IPv4-mapped addresses are written as follows:
>
> ```
> ::FFFF:<IPv4-address>
> ```

You need either to configure your system not to map IPv4 addresses as IPv6 ones, or use a library that knows how to handle those IP addresses (which are completely legit). Or in the worse case, indeed remove yourself the `::ffff:` at beginning.